# Control Template for Border

Tags: wpf, border

I would like to get a border of a particular shape, and for that, i think i need to work with the template of the border container, but i wasnt able to get the template. i tried to get the template from Expression Blend, by trying to edit the border style, but wasnt able to get it. Could someone help me out as to how i can get this template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Border` doesn't have a control template or a style because it is a decorator - it renders itself in the `OnRender` method.

If you need something shaped differently you will need to write your own decorator (inherit from the `Decorator` class). It is not very difficult. See an example here: http://blog.pixelingene.com/2007/06/balloondecorator-source-code/

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can use a content control and place the stuff you need to be border'ed as its contents, that's a codeless way of doing things.